# Emulate Javascript's 32bit signed integer arithmetic to C (or Perl) - some discrepancies

Tags: javascript, c, perl, overflow, integer-arithmetic

I am trying to translate simple JS code to C and/or Perl but I found a discrepancy in behaviour when doing arithmetic operations (`+ - * / << >>`) on integers and the result overflows. I need to simulate JS exactly, even the overflows! JS variables are not explicitly BigInt but just JS var.

JS (via node.js or Firefox's developer tools' console):

```
function calc(a, b){
 return (a<<b) + (a<<b);
}
var x = calc(1, 30);
result:
2147483648
```

C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main(void){
  int32_t lop = 1<<30; //1073741824;
  int32_t rop = 1<<30; //1073741824;
  int32_t res = lop + rop;
  printf("1<<30 + 1<<30 : %d\n", res);
}
result:
1<<30 + 1<<30 : -2147483648
```

Perl:

```
sub to32bit { unpack("l", pack("L", $_[0])) } # Corion @ PerlMonks
print to32bit(to32bit(1<<30)+to32bit(1<<30));
result:
-2147483648
```

Am I right that there is a discrepancy or am I doing things wrong?

How to get this right?

As I said I need to emulate JS's exact behaviour in C/Perl so I don't want to fix JS code but adjust C/Perl code to do the same as JS.

See also related discussion at https://perlmonks.org/?node_id=11155911

Edit Feb/2024: There is now CPAN module Math::JS (at https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::JS) by Sisyphus.

Comment: javascript has no concept of signed 32 bit in general ... your code, in javascript, just is a Number + Number ... if you want 32 bit signed ... `((a<<b) + (a << b)) | 0` that will force the answer to be the 32 bit signed you expect

Comment: I hear you! That's why that code also had what you suggested to force it to 32bit integer. My question is how to emulate that behaviour in C. Or why there is that discrepancy with C/Perl?

Comment: They are just different languages.  :-)  And `2147483648` is not a signed 32-bit value, it is one unit too big. So you could used unsigned values, or 64-bit signed ints.

Comment: In C your code invokes undefined behavior because of signed int overflow. (It was some 20 years since I coded in Perl but iirc it's the same thing there.) Meaning there is no guaranteed output or program outcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript is an implementation of ECMAScript, and ECMAScript specifies that a left-shift operation is performed as if the left operand were converted to a 32-bit two’s complement integer before the operation were performed and the right operand were converted to 32-bit unsigned integer. It also specifies that addition is performed using numbers in the IEEE-754 binary64 (“double precision”) form.

Assuming your C implementation uses binary64 for `double`, which is very common, and that `int32_t` and `uint32_t` are available (in the `<stdint.h>` header), then JavaScript `(a<<b) + (a<<b)` is largely equivalent to:

```
(double) ((int32_t) a << (uint32_t) b) + (double) ((int32_t) a << (uint32_t) b)
```

I say “largely equivalent” because details of operations involving conversion between types or handling of infinities, NaNs, and other exceptional cases may vary between ECMAScript and C.

The ECMAScript specification is explicit about the semantics of operations. If you are converting JavaScript to another language, you should get a copy of the [ECMAScript Language Specification](https://262.ecma-international.org) and use it.

Comment: *may vary between ECMAScript and C* IMO that's somewhat of an understatement.  Given `double a;`, the cast to 32-bit signed integer in `(int32_t) a` will invoke undefined behavior in C if the value of `a` can not be represented as an `int32_t`.  (I know **you** know that - but I suspect most readers likely won't appreciate the risk of using a simple cast for the conversion.)

Comment: There are some more complexities, plus the caveats mentioned. So, for the time being, it is safer and easier to shell-out the JS code to node.js. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Javascript "Numbers" are essentially `double`s, when doing bit arithmetics they are truncated to `int32`'s and then promoted back to doubles. So your C code should be something like

```
double js_shl(double a, double b) {
    return (double) ((int32_t)a << (int32_t)b);
}

double calc(double a, double b) {
    return js_shl(a, b) + js_shl(a, b);
}

int main(void){
  double res = calc(1, 30);
  printf("result : %f\n", res);
}
```

Comment: In JavaScript (ECMAScript), the right operand of a left shift is converted to `uint32_t`, not `int32_t`.